# How to pass two-dimensional array to User defined functions?

Tags: scala, dataframe, user-defined-functions, udf

Using UDF implies that each factor `c1`, `c2`, `c3` must be passed by parameter independently. Is there any flexible solution, e.g. how to pass a sequence of these factors to **UDF**?

```
val myFunction = udf {
      (userBias: Float, productBias: Float, productBiases: Map[Long, Float],
        userFactors: Seq[Float], productFactors: Seq[Float], c1: String, c2: String, c3: String) =>

        var result = Float.NaN

        // result calculation

        result
    }
```

And then I call this function the following way (`dataset` is a `DataFrame`):

```
myFunction(userBias("bias"), 
           productBias("bias"),
           productBias("biases"),
           userFactors("features"), 
           productFactors("features"),
           dataset(factors(0)), dataset(factors(1)), dataset(factors(2))
```

If I do something like this, then the compiler says "Not applicable":

```
val myFactors = dataset.select(factors.head, factors.tail: _*)

myFunction(userBias("bias"), 
           productBias("bias"),
           productBias("biases"),
           userFactors("features"), 
           productFactors("features"),
           myFactors)
```

Comment: Why the question was downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a 2d array like this:

```
val xy = Array.ofDim[Int](numrows, numcolumns);
isFunction(xy);
```

Your function definition for isFunction would look like this:

```
def isFunction(arg: Array[Array[Int]]){
    println(arg(i)(0)); // how to access array element
```